# I'm trying to copy a sheet using a sub and I'm getting error '91': Object variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

if you need any more details to feel free to ask.
thanks.

Here's the function:

```
Sub transfer(filename As Variant, sht As Worksheet)

Dim book As Workbook
Set book = Workbooks.Open(filename)

sht.Copy after:=book.Sheets(1)

book.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you calling this?

Comment: Code works for me. The cause of your problem is probably in the calling code.